# How do I define a generic object that can include any of only the properties of T?

Tags: typescript, object, generics

Below is a sample function; I want to define a generic `IncompleteVariant` that's properties are defined as having the same types as that of `T` but `IncompleteVariant` has all of `T`'s properties as potentially unset.

Theoretically a `IncompleteVariant<T>` should be allowed to be equal to `{}`.

```
/**
 * Modifies the passed `newState` to fallback on the `initialState` if any property is not set.
 */
export function orInitialState<T extends object> (newState: IncompleteVariant<T>, initialState: T): T {
  type Key = keyof T;
  if(!newState) return initialState;
  const newerState: T = {...initialState}
  for(const key of Object.keys(initialState)) {
    if(newState.hasOwnProperty(key as Key)) newerState[key as Key] = newState[key as Key]
  }
  return newerState;
}
```

How do I set up `IncompleteVariant<T>`? I have tried:

```
/**
 * Generic of object T but with all properties as optional.
 */
export type IncompleteVariant<T> = NonNullable<Partial<T>>
```

but am getting `Type 'T[keyof T] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'T[keyof T]'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'T[keyof T]'.ts(2322)`

Comment: why do not use simply Object.assign(newerState,newState) ?

Comment: const a : IncompleteVariant<null> = null; // is OK
I think i would use export type IncompleteVariant<T extends {}> = Partial<T>
enforce non null by a  constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a working version :

```
    export function orInitialState<T extends object> (newState: Partial<T>, initialState: T): T {
        type Key = keyof T;
        if (!newState) return initialState;
        const newerState: T = { ...initialState };
        for (const key of Object.keys(initialState)) {
            if (newState.hasOwnProperty(key as Key)) {
                const nskv = newState[key as Key];
                if (nskv !== undefined && nskv !== null) {
                    newerState[key as Key] = nskv;
                }
            }
        }
        return newerState;
    }
```

The mistake isn't on the `InvariantType<T>` (wich has no point to be `NonNullable <>` as T extends object).

You could not assume that newState.hasOwnProperty(key as Key) implies `newState[key as Key] !== null | undefined`.

Example : `{ a: undefined }.hasOwnProperty("a")` is `true` but `{ a: undefined }["a"]` is obviously `undefined`.

The same applies with `null` instead of `undefined`.

Edit :

If you have concerns about these "undefined vs non-existant properties", you should read about this compiler option : https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exactOptionalPropertyTypes

Comment: Why do you have to have the nskv variable declaration? I noticed if I tried to do all of the checks in the first if statement typescript still throws the same error. e.g: `newState.hasOwnProperty(key as Key) && newState[key as Key] !== undefined && newState[key as Key] !== null`

Comment: actually I'm not sure why but I think this nskv variable helps typescript refinement to get by with.

Comment: What do I do if I want the value to be null or undefined as well? The reason I opted for hasOwnProperty is because for the values that accept undefined or null values, I want to set the property value to that.

Comment: in this case I'm not sure but maybee this compiler option could help : https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exactOptionalPropertyTypes

Comment: Nice! I had no idea that option existed! It is definitely worth adding that to the answer to clarify that if undefined is intended to be allowed to add that option to the settings!